# .htaccess redirect normally for static folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file that redirects every requests to `./core/index.php`. But for static files which are in `./node_modules/` and `./assets/` folders, I want to enable normal redirect for them.

So,

1. if request: `url/whatever/page/` -> redirect to: `core/index.php`
2. if request: `url/assets/image/file.png` -> get: `assets/image/file.png`
3. if request: `url/node_modules/css/file.css` -> get: `node_modules/css/file.css`

My current code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean by "I want to enable normal redirect for them" ... What you actually show as examples looks to me as if you do not want any rewriting or redirection to get applied at all for those two base paths. If so, then there are two alternatives for this:

Either use conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node_modules/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Or explicit exceptions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?assets/ - [END]
RewriteRule ^/?node_modules/ - [END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do, is first check if it goes to assets, then redirect there, then for node_modules. And if now of that, then you redirect to the index if none of the conditions met:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/node_modules/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) node_modules/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/assets/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/node_modules/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why the checks and why the rewriting? The request examples already have the path prefix ("/assets/" and "/node_modules/"), those rules would _double_ those. So most likely break those requests.

Comment: Well i also use similar code in my framework and other routing... and it does not break at all

Comment: That is the case if the requests do _not_ already contain those prefixes. But here they do. So those rules rewrite a request to `/assets/image/file.png`to `/assets/assets/image/file.png` ... That might even implement an endless rewriting loop with that `[L]` flag ...

Comment: Really? then why did I not face any of such problems?

Comment: Check yourself: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=6106f861-8a87-4321-a374-9bf00f7bf41c